# Python XML Grab IP from File Between CDATA

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML dump file that I want to parse for the first occurrence of 'ETH0_IP'. However, the cdata field is throwing me. It ends up returning 'None'. There are other IPs that appear further in the file but I don't care about those.

I have something like this so far:

```
  q = etree.parse(outputfile)
  fileoutputip = q.findtext("ETH0_IP")
```

This is the XML:

```
<VM>
  <ID>####</ID>
  <UID>0</UID>
  <GID>0</GID>
  <UNAME>####</UNAME>
  <GNAME>###</GNAME>
  <NAME>###</NAME>
  <PERMISSIONS>
    <OWNER_U>1</OWNER_U>
    <OWNER_M>1</OWNER_M>
    <OWNER_A>0</OWNER_A>
    <GROUP_U>0</GROUP_U>
    <GROUP_M>0</GROUP_M>
    <GROUP_A>0</GROUP_A>
    <OTHER_U>0</OTHER_U>
    <OTHER_M>0</OTHER_M>
    <OTHER_A>0</OTHER_A>
  </PERMISSIONS>
  <LAST_POLL>1461191030</LAST_POLL>
  <STATE>3</STATE>
  <LCM_STATE>3</LCM_STATE>
  <PREV_STATE>3</PREV_STATE>
  <PREV_LCM_STATE>3</PREV_LCM_STATE>
  <RESCHED>0</RESCHED>
  <STIME>1461189864</STIME>
  <ETIME>0</ETIME>
  <DEPLOY_ID>###</DEPLOY_ID>
  <MEMORY>###</MEMORY>
  <CPU>0</CPU>
  <NET_TX>1000</NET_TX>
  <NET_RX>73254</NET_RX>
  <TEMPLATE>
    <AUTOMATIC_REQUIREMENTS><![CDATA[!(PUBLIC_CLOUD = YES)]]></AUTOMATIC_REQUIREMENTS>
    <CONTEXT>
      <DISK_ID><![CDATA[1]]></DISK_ID>
      <ETH0_DNS><![CDATA[####]]></ETH0_DNS>
      <ETH0_GATEWAY><![CDATA[###]]></ETH0_GATEWAY>
      <ETH0_IP><![CDATA[10.**.***.**]]></ETH0_IP>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q.findtext("ETH0_IP")` would try to find `ETH0_IP` element *directly under the root element in the tree* and in this case it results into `None` since `VM` does not have a direct `ETH0_IP` child.

You can solve it by providing the XPath expression (to look for the `ETH0_IP` element anywhere in the tree) to `find()` or `findtext()`, or by using `xpath()` method directly:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> 
>>> tree = etree.parse("input.xml")
>>> print(tree.find(".//ETH0_IP").text)
10.**.***.**
>>> print(tree.findtext(".//ETH0_IP"))
10.**.***.**
>>> print(tree.xpath("//ETH0_IP")[0].text)
10.**.***.**
```

Comment: @Publiccert You are welcome. I've also added some more relevant information to the answer, check it out.